# Updating one or more values with MarkLogic patch

Tags: marklogic, http-patch

I'm trying to use MarkLogic's patch functionality (in version 9.0-9.1) to be able to edit one or more elements of a document. In the application, a user would have a screen that is populated with the original values and be able to edit one or more of the fields, then save the edits.

I have a document like this:

```
<root>
    <value1>original value</value1>
    <value2>original value</value2>
    <value3>original value</value3>
    <value4>original value</value4>
    <value5>original value</value5>
</root>
```

I'm trying to update it using this (with one or more values of edited content):

```
<rapi:patch xmlns:rapi="http://marklogic.com/rest-api">
    <rapi:replace-insert context="/root" select="value1">original value</rapi:replace-insert>
    <rapi:replace-insert context="/root" select="value2">original value</rapi:replace-insert>   
    <rapi:replace-insert context="/root" select="value3">edited content</rapi:replace-insert>
    <rapi:replace-insert context="/root" select="value4">original value</rapi:replace-insert>
    <rapi:replace-insert context="/root" select="value5">original value</rapi:replace-insert>   
</rapi:patch>
```

However, unless every field has new content, I get the following error:

```
2020-01-29 21:25:37.425 Info: Status 500: RESTAPI-INVALIDREQ: (err:FOER0000) Invalid request:  reason: invalid patch for uri /FILE0000026.xml: replace-insert without apply or content: /root
```

Is there a way to change one or more values in the same request without dynamically updating the patch to only apply to changed values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PATCH endpoint expects the replacements to be wrapped in a container element. If you want to insert plain text, you use `<rapi:text>original value</rapi:text>`, otherwise an element of your own choosing. Note that you are **replacing** the element, so you probably want to either wrap the contents in an element, or use the child elements as context, and `text()` as select. Something like:

```
  <rapi:patch xmlns:rapi="http://marklogic.com/rest-api">
    <rapi:replace-insert context="/root/value1" select="text()">
      <rapi:text>original value</rapi:text>
    </rapi:replace-insert>
    <rapi:replace-insert context="/root/value2" select="text()">
      <rapi:text>original value</rapi:text>
    </rapi:replace-insert>   
    <rapi:replace-insert context="/root/value3" select="text()">
      <rapi:text>edited content</rapi:text>
    </rapi:replace-insert>
    <rapi:replace-insert context="/root/value4" select="text()">
      <rapi:text>original value</rapi:text>
    </rapi:replace-insert>
    <rapi:replace-insert context="/root/value5" select="text()">
      <rapi:text>original value</rapi:text>
    </rapi:replace-insert>   
  </rapi:patch>
```

See also our REST app dev guide: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/documents#id_74834

HTH!

Comment: Thanks, adding the element around the replacement text did the trick. `<rapi:replace-insert context="/root" select="value1"><value1>original value</value1></rapi:replace-insert>`